# Is $.get of jquery asynchronous?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, get

I was wondering whether I should use asynchronous calls on my website or not. I know to specify this explicitly I need to use

```
$.ajax
```

however initially I tried using `$.get` and although the server had to return lots of information, my browser didn't stuck and I could navigate without any problems.

I searched a little bit online about it, however I'm still not 100% certain about the difference between the two.

If `$.get` is asynchronous then what's the point of `$.ajax`? And if it's not, then again seeing how I had no navigation problems with `$.get`, what's the point of using `$.ajax`?

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)?

Comment: yes however since I couldn't see the point of creating a shorthand about something that is already short, I asked here to make sure.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get) is asynchronous. From the documentation:

> This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> $.ajax({
>   url: url,
>   data: data,
>   success: success,
>   dataType: dataType
> });
> ```

...and as that doesn't have the `async` option, `async` defaults to `true`. (Note that `async` will be going away entirely in a future version of jQuery; it will **always** be true.)

> If `$.get` is asynchronous then what's the point of `$.ajax`?

`$.ajax` gives you control over lot more options. `$.get` is just a shortcut.

Comment: ...shortcut with the verb GET method... as $.post stand for POST method

Answer (score 4):

[`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is simply a shorthand for:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the `jQuery` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), `$.get` is a convenience wrapper for the more low-level `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax with GET method, How about this with a promise object?

```
function showResults(name) { 
        var deferred = $.Deferred, requests = [];

        requests.push($.ajax({url:"/path/to/uri/?name=" + name, type: "GET", async: false}).done(function(d) { 
         //alert or process the results as you wish 
        }));
        $.when.apply(undefined, requests).then(function(d) { console.log(d); /*var d is a promised late return */ deferred.resolve(); }); 
        return deferred.promise();

    }
```

he returned promise object can also be used with `$.when(showResults('benjamin')).done(function() {  });` for post modifications (like chart/graph settings etc). totally reusable. You may also put this function in a loop of $.deferred requests like,

```
function updateResults() { 
             var deferred = $.Deferred, requests = [];
             requests.push($.ajax(url:"/path/to/names/?nameArr=" + jsonArrOfNames, type: "GET", async: false}).done(function(res) {  requests.push(showResults(res[0]));}) );
             $.when.apply($, requests).then(function(d) { console.log(d); /*var d is a promised late return */  deferred.resolve(); }); 
             return deferred.promise();
            }
```