# Jquery comparing to 2 different AJAX Calls - wanted to understand if there are any benifits of either

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 2 AJAX calls that achieve the same result but they are written differently. I just wanted to ask if there is any real benifit it either one or if basically they are the same:

```
$('#joinCaptchaTextBox').keyup(function() {
    $.get('scripts/ajax/script.php', {
        'join_captcha': '1',
        'captcha': $('#joinCaptchaTextBox').val()},         
        function(data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            if(obj.ajaxResponse.status) {
                $('#joinCaptchaNotAcceptable').hide();
                $('#joinCaptchaAcceptable').show();
            }else{
                $('#joinCaptchaAcceptable').hide();
                $('#joinCaptchaNotAcceptable').show();
            }
    });
});
```

And

```
$('#joinCaptchaTextBox').on('keyup', function() {
            var data = {
                    join_captcha: '1',
                    captcha : $('#joinCaptchaTextBox').val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                url : 'scripts/ajax/script.php',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function(result) {
                $('#joinCaptchaNotAcceptable').toggle(!result.ajaxResponse.status);
                $('#joinCaptchaAcceptable').toggle(result.ajaxResponse.status);
            });
});
```

I can see the second one is a little more efficent with the toggle but outside of this is either one specifically better? Just trying to understand which type to use. Note: a GET HTTP request is required.

thankyou

Comment: functionally, they are both identical. I prefer the second because i prefer being more specific with my code. $.ajax allows you to specify the options directly, where as $.get does it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajax includes two methods which are 
post and get , u can define them like below. 
$.post (or $.get) is part of ajax ,leight-weight than ajax. only include url , data , success etc methods,properties .

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "modplatform.php",
    data: "MPAx=index&proc=home::send_feedback&" + $('#feedback_send').serialize(),
    success: function (msg) {

        parent.$.fancybox.close();

        if (msg == '1') {

            MPAlert(msg, 'i');
        } else {

            MPAlert(msg, 'i');
        }

    }
});
```

}

Ajax has 
beforesend afterSend , successCode , jsonCallback etc prop and method. $.post and $.get is light weight of ajax. The same work they will do , which is up to you

Answer (score 1):

`$.get` is shorthand for `$.ajax`, so they are doing the same thing. [See the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a topic that could interest you :

[Is $.get of jquery asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671798/is-get-of-jquery-asynchronous)

I was wondering if both were asynchronous. It seems like they both express the same thing.

Comment: Seems like poeple are pretty fast on downvotes..

Comment: Or, they find this answer to be not useful. It should probably be a comment, even though you don't have the rep for that.