# Knockoutjs observable and jQuery extends function

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Let's say I have the following code:

```
var Klass = function(){
  var self = this;
  this.value = 123;

  this.update = function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/whatever', 
      async: false,
      success: function(data){
        $.extend(self, data);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Lets assume, '/whatever' returns this json object:

```
{value: 234}
```

And when I do this:

```
var obj = new Klass();
obj = ko.mapping.fromJS(obj);
console.log(obj);
```

We all know `obj` is now an knockoutjs observable.

And I run this:

```
obj.update();
console.log(obj);
```

What I have discovered is, value of `obj` doesn't get overridden as a simple value 234, but stayed as an observable property.

My questions are:

1) why is this?

2) How do I make the update work as I wanted.

UPDATE: ajax call is not asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue is that you are extending `self`, which is a scoped variable and only exists inside the Klass function, not it's instances you create by calling it.

You'll need to call `$.extend(this, data);` if you need to overwrite `value` when calling `update`. 
Although I do understand why you are using `self` there. 
But the `observable` functionality added by calling `ko.mapping.fromJS` is then lost. `value` is no longer a function (ko `observable`) but a scalar value (`234`). You have to call `obj = ko.mapping.fromJS(obj);` again to wrap value as `observable`.

Second issue is that `$.get` is [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671798/is-get-of-jquery-asynchronous) so calling `console.log(obj)` right after calling `obj.update` will log the value before the GET response comes. You need to wait for it to execute (use a callback).

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7RrKd/2/).

```
var Klass = function(){
  this.value = 123;

  this.update = function(callback){
      var self = this;
      $.get('/', function(data) {
          $.extend(self, {value: 234});
          callback.call(undefined);
      });
  }
}
var obj = new Klass();
obj = ko.mapping.fromJS(obj);
console.log(obj.value());

obj.update(function() {
    obj = ko.mapping.fromJS(obj);
    console.log(obj.value());
});
```

Comment: Yes I will call mapping again after

Comment: Hi regarding the callback, actually I am using asycn:false, I just typed this code up way more simpler here before going to sleep. But thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Also can you please explain a bit more in what `self` is without `var self = this;` inside update function?

Comment: Check this [http://jsfiddle.net/7RrKd/3/]. What you'll find is that the first `console.log(this)` is a reference to `Klass`, the other is a reference to `obj`, and this is very important. This [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript#answer-3658673] answer explains why. It's because of `new` and what it does. `Klass` is just a prototype, a _constructor_ if you will, while `obj` is an instance. Inside the constructor `this` is a reference to the constructor itself. Inside a function call of an instance (`obj`), it's referring to itself.