# knockoutjs undo ko.mapping.fromJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am aware of there is a function `ko.utils.unwrapObserable()` but it doesn't seem to unwrap an observable that is mapped by the `ko.mapping.fromJS()` at all:

```
console.log(listing);
listing = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(listing);
console.log(listing);
```

And I get the following output:

```
Object { __ko_mapping__={...}, title=c(), remote_id=c(), more...}
Object { __ko_mapping__={...}, title=c(), remote_id=c(), more...}
```

Reason I am asking for this is related to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20394977/knockoutjs-observable-and-jquery-extends-function/20395368?noredirect=1#comment30478946_20395368), basically listing is an instance of a class, which has methods reference its variables, the problem is after listing is mapped to an observable and the class methods will fail because the variables become methods.

My question is, is there a function for me to undo the mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the `ko.mapping.toJS` function (see in [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#unmapping)).

It does is the exact opposite of the `ko.mapping.fromJS` so it turns an object with observable properties to a plain JavaScript object without any observables:

```
console.log(listing);
listing = ko.mapping.toJS(listing);
console.log(listing);

Object { title="..,", remote_id="...", more...}
```

The actual implementation of the `ko.mapping.toJS` is that it recursively walks through your object properties and calls `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` on each of them.

Comment: Worth mentioning that since 2.3.0, `ko.unwrap` is available as a shorter synonym for `ko.utils.unwrapObservable`.

Comment: Ah ha! How come I didn't see this in the documentation!